# Laravel ajax deleting files fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

IN my vue js ajax post am storing file like

```
  $imagename = sha1(time()).".".$request->profile_pic->extension();
  $path = $request->profile_pic->storeAs('public/images/users',$imagename);
   $user = \Auth::user();
    //remove old file and retain new one
    if(\Storage::has($user->profile_pic)){
      \Storage::delete($user->profile_pic);
    }

   $user->picture = $path;
    $user->save();
```

THe above works and the image is saved in the `storage/app/public/images/users` which is okay

But the database field is saved as `public/images/users` so when accessing the value in the frontend its not found

After several tests i found out that in the database i need to save the file as

```
storage/images/users //note path is not starting with public
```

so i changed the

```
$user->picture="storage/images/users".$imagename;
```

But now after doing this the part that removes old file fails

```
if(\Storage::has($user->profile_pic)){
      \Storage::delete($user->profile_pic);
 }
```

How do i adjust the delete part to also work.

UPDATE FOR FULL CONTROLLER CODE

```
  public function changeProfilePic(Request $request){
  if ($request->hasFile('profile_pic')) {
    $imagename = sha1(time()).".".$request->profile_pic->extension();
    $path = $request->profile_pic->storeAs('public/images/users',$imagename);
    $user = \Auth::user();

    //remove old file and retain new one
    if(\Storage::has($user->profile_pic)){
      \Storage::delete($user->profile_pic);
    }
    $user->profile_pic = "storage/images/users".$imagename;
    //if save fails delete the uploaded image
    if($user->save()){
      return response("true", 200);
    }else {
       \Storage::delete($path);
        return response("false", 200);
    }

  }else{
    return response("false", 200);
  }
}
```

in mmy vue js during upload am using `vue-image-crop-upload` plugin

```
    <image-uploader field="profile_pic"
           ...other stuff for plugin 
             url="/change-profile-picture"
            langType="en"
            :headers="headers"
            img-format="png"></image-uploader>
```

laravel route

```
  Route::post('/change-profile-picture', 'UserController@changeProfilePic');
```

Comment: show ajax and route also full controlelr method

Comment: updated the full code.

Comment: dont store file path.only store filename  in database since file path will be static

Comment: to reduce mysql db size i believe this is the best option and also considering that i have an api been read by android volley ouputting a string and then fetching the file from storage improves on api performance

Comment: I have managed to resolve it see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i resolved it

After a quick check i found out that no matter what i try

```
Storage::has or Storage::exists
```

Aways returns false and `Storage::delete doesnt throw any error even if the file doesnt exists

Also a quick check on the file path i had to change the name stored on database from storage to public hence explde and implode

TRHe final code that works is

```
  public function changeProfilePic(Request $request){
   if ($request->hasFile('profile_pic')) {
    $imagename = sha1(time()).".".$request->profile_pic->extension();
    $path = $request->profile_pic->storeAs('public/images/users',$imagename);
    $user = \Auth::user();

    $olduserpicdata = explode("/",$user->profile_pic);
    $olduserpicdata[0] = "public";

    //remove old file and retain new one
    Storage::delete(implode("/",$olduserpicdata));
    $user->profile_pic = "storage/images/users/".$imagename;
    //if save fails delete the uploaded image
    if($user->save()){
      return response("true", 200);
    }else {
       Storage::delete($path);
        return response("false", 200);
    }

  }else{
    return response("false", 200);
  }
}
```